# taskbar shows full screen video with monitors MPCHC

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar, fullscreen, media-player-classic

I have a setup with 2 monitors attached to my computer, I then launch a full screen video on my monitor, everytime I then do something else on my other monitor the taskbar show at the buttom of the full screen video, is there any posible way to stop this or is it just how windows is build.

I run windows 7 and plays videos in Media Player Classic Home Cinema

Answer (score 0):

It's winows issue. You can solve it by using  Actual Multiple Monitors. It's great software for multi-monitor working. The function that you need called "ignore deactivation" and you can read about it here http://actualtools.com/articles/detail.php?ID=1344&sphrase_id=198087#lock_mouse

Comment: thanks, I am using display fusion and this seams to be the same things it does, but I cant get it working.

http://www.displayfusion.com/KB/PreventWindowDeactivation/